# Set options for the dropdown based on radio button select

Tags: yii, yii2

I have a form in which contains a dropdown field.The options for the dropdown is based on the radio button selection.

Radio Button

```
<?php
    $list=array("1"=>"Assign to Department","2"=>"Assign to user");
    echo $form->field($model, 'option')->radioList($list,
    [ 
        'template' => '{input}{label}', // put the label behind
    ]);
?>
```

Script

```
<script>
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){

        var Flag=this.value;
        if(Flag=='1') {
            '<?php $items= ArrayHelper::map($company->Users, 'id', 'fullname');?>';
        } else if(Flag=='2') {
            '<?php $items= ArrayHelper::map(Department::find()->all(), 'dep_id', 'name'); ?>';
        }
        alert(Flag);
    });
</script>
```

Drodown

```
<?php
    echo $form->field($model, 'assignee')
        ->dropDownList(
            $items,           // Flat array ('id'=>'label')
            ['prompt'=>'']    // options
        )->label('');
?>
```

Expected response is the change of option values according to the drop down selection.But it is not changing even though the flag value is different for radio buttons and changes on click.

Any ideas?

Comment: And that PHP code is working.I hav'nt defined the $items anywhere in my page other than in the script.Still I don't get any error.

Comment: Yes, my bad. That code will definitely work. Only that the `$items` PHP variable will be set on page load and the dropdown will get the initial array.

Comment: Just an idea - you can create 2 separate javascript arrays and set the values to them from the PHP array. Create a common javascript function, in the onclick function, pass the selected radio button to the common function. This common function can set the options to the dropdown accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried this for a sample and it works -

```
<?php
    $items1 = range(0, 5);    //PHP Array 1
    $items2 = range(5, 10);   //PHP Array 2
?>

<script>
    var arr1 = <?php echo json_encode($items1); ?>;  //Javascript Array 1
    var arr2 = <?php echo json_encode($items2); ?>;  //Javascript Array 2

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
            var Flag = this.value;
            setDropdown(Flag);
        });
    });

    function setDropdown(Flag) {
        var elem = $('#Skill_order_no'); //Your dropdown element name.
        if(Flag == '1') {
            elem.empty();
            $.each(arr1, function(index, value) {
                 elem.append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value));
            }); 
        } else if(Flag == '2') {
            elem.empty();
            $.each(arr2, function(index, value) {
                 elem.append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value));
            }); 
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @kunal..i ll definitly try dis n let u noe. :-)